# Translating yield returns in nested loops

Tags: c#

I am learning basic C#
I have the following code snippet

```
while(p!=null)
{
   foreach(var x in X)
      yield return x;
   //....
   foreach(var y in Y)
      yield return y;
   p=GetP();
}
```

Is the code above the same as

```
IEnumerable<object> os;
while (p!=null)
{   
   foreach(var x in X)
      os.Add(x);
   //....
   foreach(var y in Y)
      os.Add(y);
   p=GetP();
}
return os;
```

???

Comment: Technically no, since you can't create an `IEnumerable<T>` directly the second example won't work. Either way the first example returns items in order, `X` first, then `Y`, then calls `GetP`, whereas the second example adds them all to an enumerator and calls `GetP`. The first one may be doing something that changes how `GetP` returns and may give different results.

Comment: `IEnumerable<>` does not have an `add` method, so you can't add to it through the reference `os`.

Answer (score 5):

The two code snippets<sup>*</sup> are "the same" only in the sense that they would produce the same sequence of objects if iteration is carried out to completion. However, the actual sequence of what is going to happen during the iteration is very different.

- Code with `yield return` may be stopped early, if the loop that iterates the resultant `IEnumerable` terminates early because of a `break` or an exception.
- Code that adds to a collection prepares a new collection in memory. Code with `yield return` uses existing collections to make a sequence that can be iterated, without storing the result in memory.
- Code with `yield return` can react to changes in what it iterates during the process of the iteration. For example, if the code that uses your `yield return` method adds to collection `Y` in the process of iterating `X`, the newly items would be returned when it's time to iterate `Y`. The second code example would not be able to do the same.

<sup>*</sup> Let's pretend that `IEnumerable<T>` has an `Add` method; in reality you would probably end up using a `List<T>` or some other collection.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct in the general way that the yield works. Yield should be a little more performat than just adding to the collection because it will only be access when needed.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx):

You use a yield return statement to return each element one at a time.

You consume an iterator method by using a foreach statement or LINQ query. Each iteration of the foreach loop calls the iterator method. When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method, expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained. Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called.